# HTML on the website missing a line break from HTML in .php file

Tags: php, html

In my Notepad++ UTF8 encoded (no BOM) PHP file, there is CRLF after each line. On the front end, one of them simply disappears resulting in HTML with the line break missing. This is not echoed, it's HTML in a PHP file. Any idea why it would happen and how to solve it?

I selected the relevant piece of this file. The important thing is that the button and the div tags are all `display: inline-block` styled and I expect to have a line break between them, in order for the gaps to be displayed. The gap shows up only between the div and the 2nd button because the line break is missing on the front end for line 39.

If I do any change to this PHP file, it is correctly shown on the website, and this line break is "since always", so it's not a caching problem.

[image]

Comment: HTML doesn't care about line breaks. Any effect you get from them is not guaranteed. Don't rely on this to affect the layout of the rendered document. Stop worrying about the line break issue and instead use some suitable HTML/CSS combination to ensure that the finished document looks the way you want it to

Comment: Judging by your previous question, it looks like you've got some sort of broken HTML minimisation going on. Whether that's a PHP feature, or something else in your toolchain, I can't say.

Comment: @Alohci Many thanks for saving the day, it is Autoptimize plugin's HTML minification that ruined it for me.